# How to plot how the number of reports of contaminations in a year

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib, time-series

```
data2=pd.read_csv('Data gathered.csv', parse_dates=["DATE"])
data2['DATE'].plot()



fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
ax.plot(data2['DATE'], data2.index)
```

I want to plot a timeseries where it tells how many reports happened in a year. When I did the code above, it gave me the number of index in each reported year
I seriously have no idea what to put in my x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the `datetime` accessor `.dt` to extract the `year`, and then use `pandas.DataFrame.plot` to plot `.value_counts()`.

```py
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['DATE'].dropna().dt.year.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a little unclear what you mean by report but I assume that each row in your df is a report. Also, you say that you want the number of reports by year, so I'll suggest the following. Extract the year from the `DATE` by doing this, as well as creating a dummy variable:

```
data2['Date_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['DATE'])
data2['Year'] =data2['Date_date'].dt.year
data2['dummy'] = 1
print(data2)
```

which returns:

```
 COUNTY   Division                                          FILE NAME  \
0   HIDALGO  REM/VCIOP                                  MCDONALDS 42-1615   
1   HIDALGO   REM/DCRP                                   PRIDE'S CLEANERS   
2   HIDALGO    REM/PST                                       STRIPES 9625   
3   HIDALGO    REM/PST                               7-ELEVEN STORE 36529   
4   HIDALGO    REM/PST                               7-ELEVEN STORE 40672   
5   HIDALGO    REM/PST                          ECONOMY DRIVE INN FFP 290   
6   HIDALGO    REM/PST            FFP 297  FORMER ECONOMY DRIVE IN 114691   
7   HIDALGO    REM/PST                           FORMER GINOS MEAT MARKET   
8   HIDALGO    REM/PST                                        HOP  SHOP 1   
9   HIDALGO    REM/PST                       SAN JUANITA TREVINO PROPERTY   
10  HIDALGO    REM/PST                                       STRIPES 9634   
11  HIDALGO    REM/PST                                       STRIPES 9646   
12  HIDALGO    REM/PST                                       STRIPES 9673   
13  HIDALGO    REM/PST                                          SUNRISE 1   
14  HIDALGO    REM/PST                                             TEXACO   
15  HIDALGO    REM/PST                          AZIZ CONVENIENCE STORE 16   
16  HIDALGO    REM/PST                           AZIZ CONVENIENCE STORE 8   
17  HIDALGO    REM/PST                                         JRS XPRESS   
18  HIDALGO    REM/PST                                 SUPER OXXO STATION   
19  HIDALGO    REM/VCP                                     ADOBE REFINERY   
20  HIDALGO    REM/VCP                       AGRILIANCE EDINBURG FACILITY   
21  HIDALGO    REM/VCP                           200 WEST RAILROAD STREET   
22  HIDALGO     REM/CA                               WAL-MART STORE 93549   
23  HIDALGO    REM/PST                               23RD STREET GW PLUME   
24  HIDALGO    REM/PST                         BEST PIC CONVENIENCE STORE   
25  HIDALGO    REM/PST                        ECONOMY FOOD N GAS STORE 53   
26  HIDALGO    REM/PST                                HERNANDEZ FOOD MART   
27  HIDALGO    REM/PST                    HOP N SHOP 5 (TORTILLERIA RUIZ)   
28  HIDALGO    REM/PST                                        QUICK PIC 4   
29  HIDALGO    REM/PST                             QUICK PIC COUNTRY STOP   
30  HIDALGO    REM/VCP                       ANGLO IRON AND METAL MCALLEN   
31  HIDALGO    WPD/MSW     C & T LANDFILL (PRE-SUBTITLE D AND SUBTITLE D)   
32  HIDALGO    WPD/MSW                    CITY OF EDINBURG LANDFILL (PRE-   
33  HIDALGO    REM/VCP                           CROP PRODUCTION SERVICES   
34  HIDALGO        O&G          EAST MCCOOK CENTRAL FACILITY, PIT\nPERMIT   
35  HIDALGO        O&G   FORMER SHELL GAS WELL (1401 N. 16TH ST. MCALLEN)   
36  HIDALGO        O&G                                   GANAWAY FACILITY   
37  HIDALGO        O&G                          HAMMAN COMPRESSOR STATION   
38  HIDALGO        O&G                                      MCALLEN RANCH   
39  HIDALGO        O&G                           MONTE CHRISTO FI JOHNSON   
40  HIDALGO        O&G  SHELL MCALLEN STATION (FORMER\nCOASTAL STATES ...   

   File Number                                           LOCATION   LATITUDE  \
0         1087                   3318 US BUSINESS HWY 83, WESLACO  26.152818   
1       DC0025                          2204 WEST NOLANA, MCALLEN  26.241222   
2       120410                           721 N MCCOLL RD, MCALLEN  26.208402   
3       120290                      822 W US HIGHWAY 83, SAN JUAN  26.191568   
4       120511                            6400 S 23RD ST, MCALLEN  26.150070   
5       116761                         2015 S MCCOLL RD, EDINBURG  26.286891   
6          NaN                         1525 N TEXAS BLVD, WESLACO  26.176380   
7       120247                             700 W STATE AVE, PHARR  26.197261   
8       113110                         1417 N CONWAY AVE, MISSION  26.220368   
9       120715                      723 E UNIVERSITY DR, EDINBURG  26.300645   
10      119665                             602 W 2ND ST, MERCEDES  26.149780   
11      120448                            1601 N 10TH ST, MCALLEN  26.218037   
12      120419                          621 E NOLANA AVE, MCALLEN  26.237706   
13      103228                                   FM 1015, WESLACO  26.227820   
14       98334                            1701 S 10TH ST, MCALLEN  26.188762   
15      119730                            3000 N WARE RD, MCALLEN  26.235534   
16      119727                      2831 W US HIGHWAY 83, MCALLEN  26.207001   
17      120629                  3704 N RAUL LONGORIA RD, SAN JUAN  26.229621   
18      115176                                  FM 1015, PROGRESO  26.090420   
19        1657  ABANDONED REFINERY NO ADDRESS 0.5 MILES NORTH ...  26.298628   
20        2417                    501 E MONTE CRISTO RD, EDINBURG  26.337000   
21        2304                           200 W RAILRD ST, WESLACO  26.160388   
22       T2055  NORTHWEST CORNER OF TRENTON &FM 2061 A MCCOLL ...  26.267752   
23      117954                                   23RD ST, MCALLEN  26.213500   
24      119278                           1701 E MILE 5 N, WESLACO  26.126750   
25      119012                       601 S CLOSNER BLVD, EDINBURG  26.296313   
26      117177                    502 S SAN ANTONIO AVE, SAN JUAN  26.190150   
27      118036                             400 S CAGE BLVD, PHARR  26.191329   
28      111723                            2002 W HWY 83, MERCEDES  26.187778   
29      115600                           11110 MILE 2 E, MERCEDES  26.187778   
30         196                               2 S 21ST ST, MCALLEN  26.202780   
31   MSW00151A  S SIDE OF FM 1017, 4.0 MI W OF INT US 281 AND ...  26.580000   
32   MSW00956C                        900 E ENCINITOS RD EDINBURG  26.395000   
33        2313  WESLACO CITY BUSINESS 83 MILANO RD 3KM EAST OF...  26.165519   
34    OCP#5026              SHELL EXPLORATION AND PRODUCTION\nCO.  26.468900   
35    OCP#5159           SHELL EXPLORATION AND PRODUCTION COMPANY  26.217700   
36    OCP#5008                           MO-VAC SERVICE CO., INC.  26.383900   
37    OCP#5045  HILCORP ENERGY COMPANY (FORMERLY NEWFIELD EXPL...  26.446800   
38    OCP#2613          HILCORP (FORMERLY FOREST OIL\nPRODUCTION)  26.602200   
39    OCP#4286  HILCORP ENERGY COMPANY (FORMERLY NEWFIELD EXPL...  26.463000   
40    OCP#1837  KINDERMORGAN (FORMERLY EL PASO MERCHANT ENERGY...  26.621700   

    LONGITUDE                                       CONTAMINANTS        DATE  \
0  -97.956884                                                PAH  2018-03-20   
1  -98.237745                               CHLORINATED SOLVENTS  2005-04-29   
2  -98.211955                                   DIESEL, GASOLINE  2017-12-11   
3  -98.167134                                           GASOLINE  2016-08-22   
4  -98.254685                                           GASOLINE  2018-03-07   
5  -98.198046                                           GASOLINE  2005-10-13   
6  -97.991150                                           GASOLINE  1999-07-09   
7  -98.191799                                           GASOLINE  2017-04-24   
8  -98.325309                                           GASOLINE  1998-03-25   
9  -98.154873                                           GASOLINE  2017-11-18   
10 -97.916083                                           GASOLINE  2014-12-13   
11 -98.227928                                           GASOLINE  2017-10-20   
12 -98.206965                                           GASOLINE  2017-11-03   
13 -97.959880                                           GASOLINE  1992-06-03   
14 -98.232189                                           GASOLINE  1991-03-22   
15 -98.256408                                   GASOLINE, DIESEL  2015-06-29   
16 -98.253249                                   GASOLINE, DIESEL  2015-06-29   
17 -98.148887                                   GASOLINE, DIESEL  2018-10-16   
18 -97.958640                                   GASOLINE, DIESEL  2001-05-02   
19 -98.035970                       METALS, CHLORINATED SOLVENTS  2003-12-08   
20 -98.150698                                              OTHER  2011-07-15   
21 -97.991605                             PESTICIDES, HERBICIDES  2010-03-26   
22 -98.204565                                              SVOCS  2005-11-18   
23 -98.237100                                            UNKNOWN  1989-07-18   
24 -97.973770                                            UNKNOWN  2013-10-14   
25 -98.163493                                            UNKNOWN  2012-08-14   
26 -98.160190                                            UNKNOWN  2006-09-29   
27 -98.184896                                            UNKNOWN  2009-03-03   
28 -97.878158                                            UNKNOWN  1996-10-08   
29 -97.878158                                            UNKNOWN  2002-10-08   
30 -98.237780                                               VOCS  1996-03-07   
31 -98.180000  VOCS (1,1-DCA; CIS-1,2-DCE; DICHLORODIFLUOROME...  1995-02-13   
32 -98.131600                        VOCS (1,2-DCA; CIS-1,2-DCE)  2012-07-25   
33 -98.017608              VOCS, PESTICIDES, METALS, SVOCS, PCBS  2010-05-06   
34 -98.381000                                          TPH, BTEX         NaN   
35 -98.235100                                  CHLORIDE, TDS, AS         NaN   
36 -98.297300                                           CHLORIDE         NaN   
37 -98.289200                                     TPH, BTEX, PSH         NaN   
38 -98.265800                              BENZENE, OTHER METALS         NaN   
39 -98.319000                        TPH, BENZENE, PSH, CHLORIDE         NaN   
40 -98.316900                                     TPH, BTEX, PSH         NaN   

   ENF-STATUS ACT-STATUS 5.236                        Category  Date_date  \
0         NaN                0   Other Business Establishments 2018-03-20   
1          5B                0                    Dry cleaning 2005-04-29   
2           2               2A                     Gas Station 2017-12-11   
3           2               2A  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2016-08-22   
4           2                6  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2018-03-07   
5          1B               1A   Other Business Establishments 2005-10-13   
6          5B                6  Supermarket/Convenience stores 1999-07-09   
7           2                6  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2017-04-24   
8           2                6  Supermarket/Convenience stores 1998-03-25   
9           2                6   Other Business Establishments 2017-11-18   
10          2               2A                     Gas Station 2014-12-13   
11          2               2A                     Gas Station 2017-10-20   
12         1B               1A                     Gas Station 2017-11-03   
13          2               2A                     Gas Station 1992-06-03   
14         5B                4                     Gas Station 1991-03-22   
15          2                6                     Gas Station 2015-06-29   
16          2                6                     Gas Station 2015-06-29   
17          2                6  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2018-10-16   
18          2               2A  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2001-05-02   
19         0B                5            Oil wells/Refinaries 2003-12-08   
20         0B               2A  Industrial/Agricutural factory 2011-07-15   
21         0B               2A                         Unknown 2010-03-26   
22         0A                0  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2005-11-18   
23         5B               2A                     Gas Station 1989-07-18   
24          2               2A  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2013-10-14   
25         1B               1A                     Gas Station 2012-08-14   
26         5B               2A  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2006-09-29   
27         1B               1A  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2009-03-03   
28          2               2A  Supermarket/Convenience stores 1996-10-08   
29         1B               1A  Supermarket/Convenience stores 2002-10-08   
30         0B                5  Industrial/Agricutural factory 1996-03-07   
31         2B             4,5A                       Landfills 1995-02-13   
32         2B               2B                       Landfills 2012-07-25   
33         0B                5  Industrial/Agricutural factory 2010-05-06   
34          0                3  Industrial/Agricutural factory        NaT   
35          0               6C            Oil wells/Refinaries        NaT   
36          2               2A  Industrial/Agricutural factory        NaT   
37          0                4            Oil wells/Refinaries        NaT   
38          0                4            Oil wells/Refinaries        NaT   
39          0                4            Oil wells/Refinaries        NaT   
40          0                4            Oil wells/Refinaries        NaT   

      Year  dummy  
0   2018.0      1  
1   2005.0      1  
2   2017.0      1  
3   2016.0      1  
4   2018.0      1  
5   2005.0      1  
6   1999.0      1  
7   2017.0      1  
8   1998.0      1  
9   2017.0      1  
10  2014.0      1  
11  2017.0      1  
12  2017.0      1  
13  1992.0      1  
14  1991.0      1  
15  2015.0      1  
16  2015.0      1  
17  2018.0      1  
18  2001.0      1  
19  2003.0      1  
20  2011.0      1  
21  2010.0      1  
22  2005.0      1  
23  1989.0      1  
24  2013.0      1  
25  2012.0      1  
26  2006.0      1  
27  2009.0      1  
28  1996.0      1  
29  2002.0      1  
30  1996.0      1  
31  1995.0      1  
32  2012.0      1  
33  2010.0      1  
34     NaN      1  
35     NaN      1  
36     NaN      1  
37     NaN      1  
38     NaN      1  
39     NaN      1  
40     NaN      1
```

Then, group your dataframe by year:

```
df = data2.groupby('Year').count()
df = df.reset_index()
print(df[['Year','dummy']])
```

which return

```
  Year  dummy
0   1989.0      1
1   1991.0      1
2   1992.0      1
3   1995.0      1
4   1996.0      2
5   1998.0      1
6   1999.0      1
7   2001.0      1
8   2002.0      1
9   2003.0      1
10  2005.0      3
11  2006.0      1
12  2009.0      1
13  2010.0      2
14  2011.0      1
15  2012.0      2
16  2013.0      1
17  2014.0      1
18  2015.0      2
19  2016.0      1
20  2017.0      5
21  2018.0      3
```

Then plot

```
lines = df.plot.line(x='Year', y='dummy')
```

[image]